# Como agregar un nuevo estilo para una imagen?

Tags: android, android-layout

Estoy trantando de agregarle a una image un nuevo estilo, pero esoty un poco perdido en como hacerlo, la idea es que sobre la imagen en la parte de abajo aparesca una barra de color con un text - "nuevo empleado", estoy intentando hacerlo creado un nuevo estilo, pero en realidad no se si esta sea la mejor forma de hacerlo...espero alguien me pueda ayudar

style.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="estilo1">
    <item name="android:textColor">#a34141</item>
    <item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">15dp</item>
    <item name="android:text">Nuevo</item>
    <item name="android:background">#41a359</item>
</style>
</resources>

<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="149dp"
        android:layout_height="205dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
        android:style="@values/style.xml"
        android:src="@drawable/empl1"
        style="@style/estilo1" />
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

puedes agregar estilos a un img de esta manera :

```
<style name="TitleBarImage">     
<item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>     
<item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>     
<item name="android:src">@drawable/whiteButton</item>
```

mas info [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6598527/android-set-imageview-image-src-in-style)

Comment: Gracias por tu comentario simon.....estoy trantandole siguienod ese ejemplo, pero nopuedo hacer que el texto/estilo me qude sobre la image...me queda en la parte de atras el estilo no sobre la imagen